# Is there a way to add syntax highlighting and IntelliSense to inline styles in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, styled-components

I recently came to know of the VSCode extension [vscode-styled-components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components) that adds syntax highlighting and IntelliSense to inline style strings in js, ts, jsx, and tsx files using the `css` template literal.

Unfortunately, this extension doesn't seem to have support for .svelte files.

Is there a way to add the support myself? Or maybe there is an entirely different solution altogether?

Comment: Do you have the Svelte extension?

Comment: @H.B. Yes, I do.

Comment: You should already get completions for inline styles when just using the `style` attribute of elements. Same for the `<style>` tag. Unlike React you should generally not need to build CSS from strings.